# How to build an installer for a python application for Mac

Tags: macos, installation, pyinstaller, dmg

I have created a python application and can install it perfectly fine on Windows. I run pyinstaller to generate the executable, and then use NSIS to create an actual installer. I run the installer and it installs the application to my Program Files folder and gives me a nice desktop shortcut, etc.

What is the process to do the same for Mac? Essentially, I want to give my user a single file. When they run the file, it installs my program and any necessary libraries, and let's them launch it with a single click. I believe on Mac this is done with a .dmg or a .pkg file. What software/tools do I need to generate such a file? Do I need to restructure the project in anyway to create this?

For more info, pyinstaller creates a folder 'dist' which contains the unix executable of the application, and copies of python and any required libraries.

Note that I do not want to use the onefile option for pyinstaller because it would take a while to unpack everything each time the program is ran.

Comment: Hey, ever found a solution to this, I am kind of am in the same situation and even my reasonings are very similar.